# Web Site Administration Tool: Unable to connect to SQL Server database (using SQL Server Development Edition)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I am using the ASP.NET 2.0 and I am using local server --> SQL Server 2005 Development Edition. WHen I go into VIsual Studio 2.0  Professional and go to menu item WEBSITE --> ASP.NET CONFIGURATION, the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool shows. When I click on the Security link, after about 30 seconds an error pops saying Unable to connect to SQL Server database. I can connect to the SQL database via Server Explorer in VS 2005 and also via Grid Control etc but I keep getting the error when I try to connect via ASP.NET CONFIGURATION.

I will greatly appreciate anyone help.

THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's the problem, but the ASP.NET Configuration used to require the ASP.NET tables.  You could create those with:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -E -S localhost -A all
```

The aspnet_regsql executable can be found in:

```
C:\%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<versionNumber>\aspnet_regsql.exe
```

See also [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(VS.80).aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 1):

This answer and other research helped me get this working. I have summarized the steps in detail here http://www.yart.com.au/Resources/Programming/ASP-NET-Security-Doesnt-Work.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the connection string in a development environment and a production environment. WSAT can only be accessed locally [for a production environment] so, u have to go to ur webconfig file in Visual Studio and replace the development connection string with a production connection string. After test, reverse back to develpment connection string.
For more details see: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/users-and-roles-on-the-production-website-cs